# Parsing data array from response body json

Tags: arrays, json

My task is to create a new record in the database using a unique identifier. I have to contact the service using the GET method, from which I get a set of unique identifiers, then write them in the collection variables and then use them in my tests. I get the answer in this form. I understand that I have to parse the array of answers and write the result in a variable.

response body:

[image: response body]

starting parse:

[image: starting parse]

Comment: please provide the code in your post. also format your description please

Comment: Welcome! As written, this is off-topic, as there is no specific question. Please edit to include all relevant code, errors, etc. Also be sure to include properly-formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for more details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how correctly I solved my question, but it works the way I need it to. The answer is parsed into individual identifiers:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.collectionVariables.set("dealRef1", jsonData[0]);
pm.collectionVariables.set("dealRef2", jsonData[1]);
pm.collectionVariables.set("dealRef3", jsonData[2]);
pm.collectionVariables.set("dealRef4", jsonData[3]);
pm.collectionVariables.set("dealRef5", jsonData[4]);
```

Response Body:

```
[
"1BPMPOST9O5L0F8E9NPX",
"1BPMPOSTI5I10F8E9NPF",
"1BPMPOST0LFP0F8E9NQ5",
"1BPMPOSTIBP80F8E9NQI",
"1BPMPOSTQILO0F8E9NQC"
]
```

аnd written to Collection Variables, which I then call in my further tests.

Collection Variables:

```
dealRef1 - 1BPMPOST9O5L0F8E9NPX
dealRef1 - 1BPMPOSTI5I10F8E9NPF
dealRef1 - 1BPMPOST0LFP0F8E9NQ5
dealRef1 - 1BPMPOSTIBP80F8E9NQI
dealRef1 - 1BPMPOSTQILO0F8E9NQC
```